# Is it possible to automatically reupdate figure caption in Word thesis to a predefined multiset text format?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

Is it possible to automatically reupdate figure caption in a Word thesis to a predefined text format?

I have captions like: Figure 1. -- Decision support system for milking cows... I need to make "Figure 1" in size 12 and "Decision support system for milking cows... " in size 14.

Thesis committee requires things like that.

It is rather tedious and stupid to redefine 80 captions manually, is there any way to do the task automatically with macros?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 easy steps.

First, change the font property of the Caption style to 12 pt.

Then you just need to do a find and replace to update the text part of your captions (ie after the Figure 1, which will end in a paragraph ^13) to be 14pt.  I've assumed the . and -- should also be 14pt.

[image]